# Getting DoCmd in the correct scope or an alternative to exporting all the tables in dozens of Access databases

Tags: vba, ms-access

What I'm trying to do is pretty simple:

- Iterate through all of the `.accdb` files in a directory
- Open them and export all the tables to separate `.xlsx` files

The issue I'm running into is the scope of `DoCmd` and I'm having difficulty changing it. The issue is coming up because I'm running the VBA from what is basically and empty `Database1.accdb`. When the VBA gets to `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet`, it is using `CurrentDb` and not the Access file that was opened with `OpenDatabase`. It is saying a table that is clearly does see (`Debug.Print(tbl.Name)` works) doesn't exist.

See below:

```
Option Compare Database

Public Const PROJECT_PATH = "\\192.168.1.2\Migration\"
Public Const DESC_PATH = PROJECT_PATH & "Descriptions\"
Public Const DESC_DB_PATH = DESC_PATH & "DBs\"
Public Const DESC_EXPORTS = DESC_PATH & "Exports\"
Sub ExportDescriptionTables()

    Dim wrkSpace As Workspace, _
        db As Database, _
        tbl As TableDef

    ' ************************** TEMPLATE FILES - BEGIN *************************
    Set dbDirObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set dbFolder = dbDirObj.GetFolder(DESC_DB_PATH)
    Set dbFiles = dbFolder.Files
    ' ************************** TEMPLATE FILES - END ***************************

    ' Create the Access object for this file
    Set wrkSpace = CreateWorkspace("", "admin", "", dbUseJet)

    ' Iterate through each Access file
    For Each dbFile In dbFiles
           
        ' Open each Access database file
        Set db = wrkSpace.OpenDatabase(DESC_DB_PATH & dbFile.Name)
         
        ' Iterate through each table
        For Each tbl In db.TableDefs
        
            ' Export based on the table name matching specific criteria
            If Left(tbl.Name, 1) <> "~" And Left(tbl.Name, 4) <> "MSys" Then
            
                Debug.Print (tbl.Name)
                ' ################### THIS WHERE THE ERROR OCCURES ############## 
                DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, tbl.Name, DESC_EXPORTS & tbl.Name & dbFile.Name, True, tbl.Name
            End If
            
        Next tbl
        
        ' Close database
        db.Close
                
        ' Clear out access object for this file
        Set db = Nothing
    Next dbFile

End Sub
```

So my questions:

1. Is there a way I'm simply not seeing for setting the scope of `DoCmd`?
2. If not, what would be a better approach to this (perhaps running from Excel potentially forcing the `CurrentDb` to be the only open Acccess DB, which should bring `DoCmd` into proper scope)?

Comment: ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.transferdatabase  `With a linked table, you have access to the table's data while the table itself remains in the other database.` - haven't really read it to see what linking involves. Not an Access person myself but there are plenty of them about on here

Comment: Nope tried the `db.DoCmd` and `Method or data member not found` is what comes up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No. Always think of `DoCmd` as something a user can do via the user interface.
2. When located a database and the table(s) within this to export, *link* this/these to the main database (with `DoCmd.TransferDatabase`), then export each linked table and delete it afterwards.

Comment: That is a good idea: automate linking all the tables to this `Database1.accdb` and then exporting from there. I'll give that a shot

Answer (score 1):

`DoCmd` is a child of an `Application` object.  You can create a new Access application session and  open your target database there.  Then when you call `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet` within that session, it will look within its "own" database for the names of the tables (or queries) you ask it to export.

Here's a simple example, which exports just one table from one database.

```vb
Dim objAccess As Object

Set objAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")
'objAccess.Visible = True ' useful during development and for trouble-shooting

objAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase "C:\Temp\Northwind_2007.accdb"
objAccess.DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, _
    "Customers", "C:\Temp\Customers.xlsx"

objAccess.CloseCurrentDatabase
objAccess.Quit
```